# Insert HTML file into outlook message using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a html file that works well in an outlook message when inserted as text. I am trying to make it easier for my client by inserting the html file using vba, however I am having trouble knowing how to insert the file as text.

I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to set up the [MailItem.HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property which sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties. 
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 'Create email item 
 Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 With objMail 
   'Set body format to HTML 
   .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
   .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>" 
   .Display 
 End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene, my problem is that the html file is rather large and the .HTMLBody would need to be the text in the file. That is the part I am having trouble with.

Comment: I have it working. If anyone is interested, the code is below

Comment: Sub CreateHTMLMail()
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties.
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
 'Create email item
Dim iFile As Integer
Dim strVar As String

iFile = FreeFile
Open "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\HTML\Index1.html" For Input As #iFile 'first text file
strVar = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
Close #iFile
 
Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objMail
   'Set body format to HTML
   .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
   .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>" & strVar & "</BODY></HTML>"
   .Display
End With
 
End Sub

Comment: Sorry I don't know how you format it on here. I entered it as it was from the code but it has text wrapped it.

Comment: Basically you need to read the text of the HTML file and set it to the `HTMLBody` property.